# Angular material 2 get rid of md-select errors after resetting formGroup

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using angular material for Angular 2 and above (https://material.angular.io) and facing the following problem:

I have a form with a bunch of inputs and an md-select element, after submitting the form i reset it using the following technique as described in this post: 
(https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4190)

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="myFormGroup" #f="ngForm">
  ...
</form>
```

Component class:

```
@ViewChild('f') myNgForm;

reset() {
  this.myNgForm.resetForm();
}
```

The errors disappear from the inputs but this is not the case for the md-select.

After debugging i noticed that even after resetting the form the class mat-select-invalid still associated with the md-select.

is there any solution ?

thx in advance.